# Integrated WebLogic Server running issue in JDeveloper unable to find domain default folder

Tags: jdeveloper

---

PATH=;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\wlserver\server\native\win\x64;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\wlserver\server\bin;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\oracle_common\modules\org.apache.ant_1.9.2\bin;C:\PROGRA~1\Java\jdk-1.8\jre\bin;C:\PROGRA~1\Java\jdk-1.8\bin;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\wlserver\server\native\win\x64\oci920_8;C:\PROGRA~2\COMMON~1\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\ofss\WINDOW~1.X64\bin;C:\Windows\System32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH;C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~4\160\Tools\Binn;C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~4\160\Tools\Binn;C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~4\CLIENT~1\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn;C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~4\160\DTS\Binn;C:\PROGRA~1\AZURED~1\bin;C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~4\160\DTS\Binn;C:\Users\JASMIN~1\DOWNLO~1\APACHE~2.5-B\APACHE~1.5\bin;C:\Users\JASMIN~1\DOWNLO~1\JAXB-R~1.1\jaxb-ri\bin;C:\Users\JASMIN~1\DOWNLO~1\JAXB-R~1.1;C:\PROGRA~1\Git\cmd;C:\PROGRA~1\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\PROGRA~1\Git\usr\bin;C:\PROGRA~1\Java\jdk-1.8\bin;C:\Users\JASMIN~1\AppData\Roaming\MICROS~1\Windows\STARTM~1\Programs\PYTHON~1.12;C:\Users\JASMIN~1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\PYTHON~1\Scripts;C:\Users\JASMIN~1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\PYTHON~1;C:\Users\JASMIN~1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Launcher;C:\Users\JASMIN~1\AppData\Local\MICROS~1\WINDOW~1;C:\Users\JASMIN~1\AppData\Local\Programs\MICROS~1\bin;C:\PROGRA~1\AZURED~1\bin;C:\Users\JASMIN~1\AppData\Local\GITHUB~1\bin;C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\soa\soa\thirdparty\edifecs\XEngine\bin
.
JAVA_OPTIONS=-Doracle.jdeveloper.adrs=true -Dweblogic.nodemanager.ServiceEnabled=true  -Xverify:none  -Djava.system.class.loader=com.oracle.classloader.weblogic.LaunchClassLoader
.

---

** End SOA Specific environment setup  for win.

---

.
.
JAVA Memory arguments: -Xms1024m -Xmx2048m -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
.
CLASSPATH=C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\soa\soa\modules\user-patch.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\soa\soa\modules\soa-startup.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oracle_common\modules\features\com.oracle.db.jdbc7-dms.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oracle_common\modules\odsi_xquery2004_12.1.3\odsi.xquery.modules_12.1.3.0.jar;C:\PROGRA~1\Java\jdk-1.8\lib\tools.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\wlserver\server\lib\weblogic.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\oracle_common\modules\net.sf.antcontrib_1.1.0.0_1-0b3\lib\ant-contrib.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\wlserver\modules\features\oracle.wls.common.nodemanager.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\soa\soa\modules\oracle.soa.common.adapters_11.1.1\oracle.soa.common.adapters.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\soa\soa\modules\oracle.cloud.adapter_12.1.3\oracle.cloud.adapter.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\osb\lib\servicebus-common.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oracle_common\communications\modules\config.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oracle_common\communications\modules\userprefs-config.jar;C:\Users\JASMIN~1\AppData\Roaming\JDEVEL~1\SYSTEM~1.164\DEFAUL~1\config\soa-infra;C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\soa\soa\modules\quartz-all-1.6.5.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\soa\soa\modules\oracle.soa.fabric_11.1.1\oracle.soa.fabric.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\soa\soa\modules\oracle.soa.fabric_11.1.1\fabric-runtime-ext-wls.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\soa\soa\modules\oracle.soa.adapter_11.1.1\oracle.soa.adapter.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\soa\soa\modules\oracle.soa.b2b_11.1.1\oracle.soa.b2b.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oracle_common\modules\internal\features\jrf_wlsFmw_oracle.jrf.wls.classpath.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\soa\soa\modules\oracle.soa.fabric_11.1.1\tracking-api.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\soa\soa\modules\commons-cli-1.1.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\soa\soa\modules\oracle.soa.mgmt_11.1.1\soa-infra-mgmt.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\osb\lib\version.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\osb\lib\servicebus.jar;C:\Users\JASMIN~1\AppData\Roaming\JDEVEL~1\SYSTEM~1.164\DEFAUL~1\config\osb;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\wlserver\common\derby\lib\derbynet.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\wlserver\common\derby\lib\derbyclient.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\wlserver\common\derby\lib\derby.jar
.
PATH=C:\Users\JASMIN~1\AppData\Roaming\JDEVEL~1\SYSTEM~1.164\DEFAUL~1\bin;;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\wlserver\server\native\win\x64;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\wlserver\server\bin;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\oracle_common\modules\org.apache.ant_1.9.2\bin;C:\PROGRA~1\Java\jdk-1.8\jre\bin;C:\PROGRA~1\Java\jdk-1.8\bin;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\wlserver\server\native\win\x64\oci920_8;C:\PROGRA~2\COMMON~1\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\ofss\WINDOW~1.X64\bin;C:\Windows\System32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH;C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~4\160\Tools\Binn;C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~4\160\Tools\Binn;C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~4\CLIENT~1\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn;C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~4\160\DTS\Binn;C:\PROGRA~1\AZURED~1\bin;C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~4\160\DTS\Binn;C:\Users\JASMIN~1\DOWNLO~1\APACHE~2.5-B\APACHE~1.5\bin;C:\Users\JASMIN~1\DOWNLO~1\JAXB-R~1.1\jaxb-ri\bin;C:\Users\JASMIN~1\DOWNLO~1\JAXB-R~1.1;C:\PROGRA~1\Git\cmd;C:\PROGRA~1\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\PROGRA~1\Git\usr\bin;C:\PROGRA~1\Java\jdk-1.8\bin;C:\Users\JASMIN~1\AppData\Roaming\MICROS~1\Windows\STARTM~1\Programs\PYTHON~1.12;C:\Users\JASMIN~1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\PYTHON~1\Scripts;C:\Users\JASMIN~1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\PYTHON~1;C:\Users\JASMIN~1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Launcher;C:\Users\JASMIN~1\AppData\Local\MICROS~1\WINDOW~1;C:\Users\JASMIN~1\AppData\Local\Programs\MICROS~1\bin;C:\PROGRA~1\AZURED~1\bin;C:\Users\JASMIN~1\AppData\Local\GITHUB~1\bin;C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\soa\soa\thirdparty\edifecs\XEngine\bin
.

---

- To start WebLogic Server, use a username and   *
- password assigned to an admin-level user.  For *
- server administration, use the WebLogic Server *
- console at http:\hostname:port\console        *

---

Starting WLS with line:
C:\PROGRA~1\Java\jdk-1.8\bin\java -server   -Xms1024m -Xmx2048m -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -Dweblogic.Name=DefaultServer -Djava.security.policy=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\wlserver\server\lib\weblogic.policy -Doracle.jdeveloper.adrs=true -Dweblogic.nodemanager.ServiceEnabled=true  -Xverify:none  -Djava.system.class.loader=com.oracle.classloader.weblogic.LaunchClassLoader -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs="oracle.mds.net.protocol|oracle.fabric.common.classloaderurl.handler|oracle.fabric.common.uddiurl.handler|oracle.bpm.io.fs.protocol|com.bea.wli.sb.resources.url" -Dopss.version=12.2.1.2 -Digf.arisidbeans.carmlloc=C:\Users\JASMIN~1\AppData\Roaming\JDEVEL~1\SYSTEM~1.164\DEFAUL~1\config\fmwconfig\carml -Digf.arisidstack.home=C:\Users\JASMIN~1\AppData\Roaming\JDEVEL~1\SYSTEM~1.164\DEFAUL~1\config\fmwconfig\arisidprovider -Doracle.security.jps.config=C:\Users\JASMIN~1\AppData\Roaming\JDEVEL~1\SYSTEM~1.164\DEFAUL~1\config\fmwconfig\jps-config.xml -Doracle.deployed.app.dir=C:\Users\JASMIN~1\AppData\Roaming\JDEVEL~1\SYSTEM~1.164\DEFAUL~1\servers\DefaultServer\tmp_WL_user -Doracle.deployed.app.ext=- -Dweblogic.alternateTypesDirectory=C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oracle_common\modules\oracle.ossoiap,C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oracle_common\modules\oracle.oamprovider,C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oracle_common\modules\oracle.jps -Doracle.mds.filestore.preferred=true -Dadf.version=12.2.1.1.0 -Dweblogic.jdbc.remoteEnabled=true -Dcommon.components.home=C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oracle_common -Djrf.version=12.2.1 -Dorg.apache.commons.logging.Log=org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Jdk14Logger -Ddomain.home=C:\Users\JASMIN~1\AppData\Roaming\JDEVEL~1\SYSTEM~1.164\DEFAUL~1 -Doracle.server.config.dir=C:\Users\JASMIN~1\AppData\Roaming\JDEVEL~1\SYSTEM~1.164\DEFAUL~1\config\fmwconfig\servers\DefaultServer -Doracle.domain.config.dir=C:\Users\JASMIN~1\AppData\Roaming\JDEVEL~1\SYSTEM~1.164\DEFAUL~1\config\fmwconfig -Doracle.osb.home=C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\osb  -javaagent:C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\wlserver\server\lib\debugpatch-agent.jar -da -Dwls.home=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\wlserver\server -Dweblogic.home=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\wlserver\server  -Djps.app.credential.overwrite.allowed=true -Djavax.management.builder.initial=weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServerBuilder  -da:org.apache.xmlbeans... -Dem.oracle.home=C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\em -DINSTANCE_HOME=C:\Users\Jasmine Kaur\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system12.2.1.2.42.161008.1648\DefaultDomain -Djava.awt.headless=true -Doracle.sysman.util.logging.mode=dual_mode -Dweblogic.configuration.schemaValidationEnabled=false -Dsoa.archives.dir=C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\soa\soa -Dsoa.oracle.home=C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\soa -Dsoa.instance.home=C:\Users\JASMIN~1\AppData\Roaming\JDEVEL~1\SYSTEM~1.164\DEFAUL~1 -Dtangosol.coherence.log=jdk -Djavax.xml.soap.MessageFactory=oracle.j2ee.ws.saaj.soap.MessageFactoryImpl -Dweblogic.transaction.blocking.commit=true -Dweblogic.transaction.blocking.rollback=true -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\wlserver\server\lib\DemoTrust.jks -Doracle.xml.schema\Ignore_Duplicate_Components=true -Doracle.xdkjava.compatibility.version=11.1.1 -Doracle.soa.compatibility.version=11.1.1 -Ddisable-implicit-bean-discovery=true -Dums.oracle.home=C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oracle_common   -Djava.util.logging.manager=oracle.core.ojdl.logging.ODLLogManager  weblogic.Server
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option PermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=1024m; support was removed in 8.0
Error: Could not find or load main class Kaur\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system12.2.1.2.42.161008.1648\DefaultDomain
Stopping Derby server...
Derby server stopped.
[Starting IntegratedWebLogicServer.]
[waiting for the server to complete its initialization...]
Process exited.
[IntegratedWebLogicServer terminated.]

after creating the default domain started the server but its showing error as written above

Comment: Any reason why you use the SOA version of ADF? The log shows the real error as " **Error: Could not find or load main class**". Can you elaborate on what you have tried to do?